# Puppeteer: how to wait all screenshot end before browser close?

Tags: puppeteer

Well, I want to screenshot every 20ms during the puppeteer open a page until browser close.However, for the screenshot speed is so fast and it's a long time to generate a pic. So if browser was close, there will be many pics can't be stored.How can I wait all screentshot done before browser close?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to store the data in an array in the higher scope, so that even if the browser closes you can still do some operations in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using async/await with your page and browser calls? Try this:

```
(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(inputImgUrl, {waitUntil: 'networkidle'});
    await page.setViewport(viewPortData);
    await page.screenshot({path: outputFile, type: 'jpeg', quality: 50, clip: cropData});
    await browser.close();
})();
```